# Uploading a pdf to rails using paperclip not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, file-upload, paperclip

I am using paperclip to upload pdf's to my db. However the PDF isn't uploaded into the db, it just creates a blank entry, like so:

```
      2.1.0 :001 > YearlyGuide.last
         YearlyGuide Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "yearly_guides".* FROM "yearly_guides"   ORDER       BY "yearly_guides"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
                => #<YearlyGuide id: 2, pdf_file_name: nil, pdf_content_type: nil, pdf_file_size: nil, pdf_updated_at: nil, start: nil, end: nil, created_at: "2014-06-09 14:10:50", updated_at: "2014-06-09 14:10:50">
```

my controller looks like this:

```
   def new
@yearguide = YearlyGuide.new
```

end

```
 def create
@yearguide = YearlyGuide.create
if @yearguide.save
  redirect_to '/' 
else
  render 'new'
end
```

end

and my model this:

```
   class YearlyGuide < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :pdf
    validates_attachment :pdf, content_type: { content_type: "application/pdf" }
    end
```

my new.html.erb this:

```
     <%= bootstrap_form_for(@yearguide, layout: :horizontal, label_col: "col-sm-2", control_col: "col-sm-10") do |f| %>
```

```
<%= f.date_select :end %>

<%= f.file_field :pdf, help: "Ensure images are minimum 400x400px"  %>
<%= f.submit "Add Event", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Why isn't the file being uploaded? what am I missing? Are there erros with my code?

Comment: does your form has the HTML property `multipart="true"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 3

```
def create
  @yearguide = YearlyGuide.new(params[:yearly_guide])
  if @yearguide.save
    redirect_to '/' 
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Rails 4

```
def create
  @yearguide = YearlyGuide.new(yearly_guide_params)
  if @yearguide.save
    redirect_to '/' 
  else
    render 'new'
  end  
end

def yearly_guide_params
  params.require(:yearly_guide).permit(:pdf)
end
```

In short you're using `.create` but passing no parameters, because you've got the `if @yearguide.save` you want new.  If you actually want create just sub in create in my answer above - leaving the params part.

Comment: +1 Adding a note about `yearly_guide_params` in your answer would be great.

Comment: @KirtiThorat right you are.  I don't use paperclip though so don't know if just permitting pdf will work.

Comment: Yes. It would work. Check the [Paperclip Documentation: For Rails 4 Strong Parameters](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#controller)

Comment: but where does the file actually get stored? This seems to just create a YearlyGuide record but where does the pdf file actually go?

Comment: @Jwan622 [Paperclip documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#storage) you set it via paperclip